# Simple VBA to advance through the sheets in a workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a simple VBA to advance through the sheets in a workbook to find the first sheet where a specific cell location is blank. Example, I have workbook with dated tabs for the whole year, and in cell E1 I fill in the days date. Today I want to copy data from another export file, then in my dated file loop through the sheets until it finds the first sheet where cell E1 would be blank, then do my copy paste function to. During the copy paste function I will paste the date into cell E1 so when to looks the next day it will by-pass that sheet. Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: `For each worksheet in workbook.worksheets`

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try:

```
Sub BlankFinder()
    For Each sh In Sheets
        If sh.Range("E1") = "" Then
            MsgBox "E1 found blank in sheet " & sh.Name
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next sh
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. This sort of worked. Just a direct copy paste and running it, it did find and return the sheet where the cell was empty. Then when I attempted to modify it, I added a couple lines to copy and paste from another file and it did not paste to the sheet where the empty cell was located. It pasted to the sheet where the workbook was left open. I think what I need is something so that after it finds the empty cell that it makes that sheet active without specifically naming the sheet so that when the next piece, the copy paste, happens it does it on the correct sheet.